# How do I change the Favicon for my SharePoint install?

Tags: design

Fairly straightforward, I think.  I'm running a SharePoint 2010 instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sean Earp's answer was extremely helpful, but the details were essentially off for my particular situation.  Here are the steps I took to accomplish what I wanted:

1. I put a copy of the favicon.ico I wanted to use in the /images/ folder by using SharePoint Designer.
2. I then went into "Master Pages", right-clicked on "v4.master", hovered over "Open With", and selected "SharePoint Designer (Open as Text)".
3. Then I had to find the following line within the head section: `<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/_layouts/images/favicon.ico" __designer:Preview="&lt;link rel=&quot;shortcut icon&quot; href=&quot;/_layouts/images/favicon.ico&quot; type=&quot;image/vnd.microsoft.icon&quot; /&gt;" __designer:Values="&lt;P N='IconUrl' T='/_layouts/images/favicon.ico' /&gt;&lt;P N='InDesign' T='False' /&gt;&lt;P N='ID' T='ctl10' /&gt;&lt;P N='Page' ID='1' /&gt;&lt;P N='TemplateControl' ID='2' /&gt;&lt;P N='AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory' R='-1' /&gt;"/>`
4. All I had to do at this point was remove the three instances of the string `/_layouts` as that would then point to the file I wanted to use.

I didn't need to insert a new `<link/>` line.  In fact when I tried to it wouldn't use the line I inserted even though it would still show up after viewing the page's source.

All that was left was to set v4.master as the Default master page.

Answer (score 6):

Courtesy of Randy Drisgill: http://blog.drisgill.com/2008/02/favicons-in-sharepoint-master-page.html

> Drag a favicon.ico file to the Images
>   directory of your MOSS site with
>   SharePoint designer.
>
> Add the following line to your Master
>   Page at the bottom of the head section
>   right before the `</head>` tag:
>
> ```
> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" />
> ```
>
> Check-in, publish, and approve your
>   Master Page so that anonymous folks
>   can see the change.

Comment: I've followed the instructions but I can't get the cached favicon to clear.  What would you suggest?

Comment: It's possible the icon is cached.  Does it show up if you try a different browser?  If you look at the source code of the page (using the Developer Tools with the F12 key), does your updated link to favicon show up?

Comment: You know what, which file am I meant to be modifying?  v4.master?  default.master?

Comment: Whatever master page is applied to your site :)

Comment: I have found these same instructions on several sites.  It works with FF and Chrome but not IE (a little ironic).

Answer (score 0):

Hi have a look the article, which explains about creating and using favicon for SP 2010.
[Changing Favicon in SharePoint 2010](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2012/05/changing-favicon-in-sharepoint-2010.html)